# What does " turning into the skid " mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Tommy    must    have    tried   to  gun     the
engine  while   turning into    the skid,   but it  didn’t  work.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. What research have you done? Could you cite your research, please?

Comment: "Steer into the skid" is more idiomatic.

Comment: @HotLicks - That may be regional; while it's generally _taught_ using 'steer' in my area, I'd say that in practice both are used about equally.

Answer (score 3):

If a motor vehicle loses traction, it ‘skids’. To recover from the skid, the driver tries to align the vehicle’s principal axis with the direction of motion; this is usually done by manipulating the steering mechanism. This manipulation of the steering mechanism normally causes the vehicle to turn (that is, change direction), and ‘turning’ is normally the word used. To ‘turn into the skid’ is thus to manipulate the steering mechanism to cause the vehicle’s principal axis to align with the direction of motion after losing traction.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are driving on a slippery road, and your car starts to skid to the left.  Your natural instinct is to turn the wheel to the right, as a correction.  But that will make it harder for you to regain control of the car.

Instead, you should **turn into the skid**, meaning, turn your wheel gently to the left.  This might seem counterintuitive.  But it helps you establish traction with the road again, and then you'll hopefully be able to start steering again in the direction you actually want to go.

Comment: Thank you so very much now it's clear